# Why the attribute "provide_basic_symbols" is not recognized in jitcode?

Tags: python-3.x, jitcode-jitcdde-jitcsde

I am trying to solve a DAE in a python code on a Windows visual studio code.
However, I cannot import some attributes of the module `jitcode` receiving the following error message:

```
AttributeError: module 'jitcode' has no attribute 'provide_basic_symbols'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`provide_basic_symbols` was an overly complicated construction in early versions of JiTC*DE that was discontinued years ago (with the 1.0 release, IIRC). Instead you can now import the “basic symbols” directly:

```
from jitcode import y,t
```

Note that JiTCODE does not solve DAEs out of the box, only ODEs (to which some DAEs can be transformed).